# How to write raw multipart SOAP HTTP message to output with Grails

Tags: http, grails, http-headers, multipart

I have a Grails application that should respond with previously stored raw SOAP messages. These messages are read from a database. When I write the message to output, it is added to body part of the HTTP response. The results is that reading the response on client end fails as the HTTP headers etc are part of the body. The results on client side looks something like this

```
------=_Part_0_1123526246346
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <some-id>

<soap:Envelope>
<!-- Message contents -->
</soap:Envelope>

------=_Part_0_1123526246346
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <temp.pdf>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="temp.pdf"

<!-- Lots of binary data -->

%%EOF
------=_Part_0_1123526246346--
```

All this means that it's a multipart SOAP message where a PDF doc comes as an attachment. The messages written to DB are consumed correctly by the client and only the soap envelope is seen as the body, PDF as an attachment.

**How can I write this message as RAW ouput with Grails, so that the HTTP stuff does not end up being duplicated?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need full control of the `response` produced by a controller, including headers, then you should look at the [response](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/response.html) object which is available. Every controller in Grails has access to the [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) through the `response` object so you can manage the raw response yourself.

However, your problem is that you need a multi-part response and the HTTP headers are embedded in your text. You should be able to parse them out and manually create a [MultiPartResponse](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartResponse.html) using the [famous package](http://www.servlets.com/cos/) from Jason Hunter.

With a bit of parsing of your data, combining the `HttpServletResponse` available in Grails and the `MultipartResponse` you should be able to get the results you need.

Another possible option is to simply set the headers on the HttpServletResponse to indicate it's a multi-part response and write the text/data straight to the output stream. This may or may not work depending on how it's being consumed, but it's worth a try.

```
// some controller method
response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace")
response.outputstream << theDataAsAByteArray
```

Comment: Setting the content-type to multipart does not work with the clients I used. SoapUI hangs after the first response (which is OK by the way) and spring-WS gives an error on incorrect content-type.

Comment: Using the MultipartResponse package is not possible in this case due to the license terms. Thanks for the suggestions, though.

Comment: Setting the content-type to `multipart/related` seems to work for SoapUI, but Spring-WS has a problem: `Missing Start Boundary, or boundary does not start on a new line`. Keeping the question still open in hope for other great input on this.

Comment: After reading about multipart HTTP messages, I finally managed to get this one solved. Setting content type to `multipart/related` was one key thing. Also need to have the `boundary` set in the header, which in this case was an extra burden as the boundary part contains hyphens in the beginning. For the header to work correctly, two first hyphens needed to be removed.